# Why I can't add more keys to a dict? - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, error-handling

I have a program where I want to add more keys to a dictionary.

When I add only one key, everything is OK:

```
dict = {}
dict["key1"] = "Value"
print(dict)

//{'key1':'value'}
```

But when I add a second key, I get an error message:

```
dict = {}
dict["key1"]["key2"] = "Value"
print(dict)

//Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***", line 2, in <module>
    dict["key1"]["key2"] = "value"
  KeyError: 'key1'
```

How can I add more keys?

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but you should not use reserved keywords like `dict` for your variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dict['key1'] = {'key2': 'value'}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is that accessing the `dict["key1"]` which is `"Value"` and then you are trying to `"Value"["key2"] = "value"`

so if you want to add a second key

```py
dict = {}
dict["key1"] = "Value1"
dict["key2"] = "Value2"

print(dict)
# {"key1": "Value1", "key2": "Value2"}
```

and if you are trying to assign a subdictionary

```py
dict = {}
dict["key1"] = {}
dict["key1"]["key2"] = "Value2"

print(dict)
# {"key1": {"key2": "Value2"}}
```

which is also

````py
dict = {}
dict["key1"] = {"key2": "Value2"}

print(dict)
# {"key1": {"key2": "Value2"}}
```python
````

Answer (score 0):

You can add another dictionary as value inside the fisrt dictionary under the first key, then you can add items to that one using "double"-keys:

```
d1 = {"some_key" : {"another_dicts_key": 42} }  # 1st dict contains other dict 

print(d1["some_key"]["another_dicts_key"])
```

Output:

```
42
```

Adding more keys to the initial dictionary is as easy:

```
d1["other"] = 84
```